# Error 500 on Wordpress backend after installing plugin

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I think this is a little too much for me. I have plugins installed and activated before and My site is working just fine. But when i tried to add plugins or activate new ones, i get a http error 500:

**The www.mydomain.ie page isn’t working**

**www.mydomain.ie is currently unable to handle this request.**

I've tried the suggestions on forums and other sites that i could look into, but i still cant solve this. I also couldn't reproduce this error in my localhost(localhost/mydomain) and its working properly there.

In my htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 53

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What's weird is that i dont get anything in the error log

[image]

The only thing i haven't done yet is deactivating the plugins because my site has visitors. But, if all else fails, i guess i'll do just that. Any thought on this? any help would be appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: there is a issue in your .htaccess file. 
update your question with .htaccess file and siteurl.(siteurl is in wp-option table's first row)

Comment: Do you have access to your server error log?

Comment: @BrettGregson i forgot, my error log does not display any error. wierd...

Comment: @Bhavin I updated my question.

Comment: .htaccess looks fine now try with renaming your .htaccess file. rename it so it will not make any effect . try it and tell me. and it's not a plugin issue so no need think about deactivate

Comment: @Bhavin i renamed it to .htaccess_old. nothing happened.

Comment: Try turn errors on in your PHP ini and add this to your htaccess `php_flag display_errors on`

Comment: Ohk so you have to find out from where the 500 error come . First of all rename plugin folder with plugin_old etc it will temporary deactivate all plugin if error goes then there is a faulty plugin ...

Comment: @BrettGregson i did what you said, error logs still wont display. did i miss something? i added php_flag display_errors on at the end of the htaccess

Comment: In your wp-config.php in your root directory, try add: 
`define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

Comment: @Bhavin well, i deactivated all my plugins. Found out that 2 of them were the cause of it. Thanks for the help guys.